# Overriding default TextBlock style on a ContentPresenter in a ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have found a bunch of responses for this same problem but none that really answer the question from what I can tell...  I'm trying to set the foreground of the header in the default GroupBox style for my application to a different color than rest of the content.  Consider the following:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                <ContentPresenter TextElement.Foreground="Green" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now, if I set the header on the GroupBox to just a string like so, the font is correctly green:

```
<Grid>
    <GroupBox Header="Header Text"/>
</Grid>
```

However if I change it so the header is a control, the font color from the style is not applied:

```
<Grid>
    <GroupBox>
        <GroupBox.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Header Text"/>
        </GroupBox.Header>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

From what I understand, this is due to the fact that the ContentPresenter just has a string in the first example, so it is creating the TextBlock itself and is therefore its parent in the visual tree, while in the second example the content gets created first then just gets inserted where the ContentPresenter would have otherwise been.

So I know *why* this happens...  But I haven't been able to track down a good workaround.  In other examples I've seen people usually end up explicitly templating the content, however this is just a default style for my application so I don't have the content to explicitly set anything on.

Comment: It is possible to set default color, but will apply for all `TextBlock`s you have inside GroupBox, include `GroupBox`'s content. Is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

If this `GroupBox` is a one or two-time thing, then I'd suggest just simply giving the `GroupBox` in question an `x:Name="Whatever"` and then binding all the `TextBlock`'s properties you want it to inherit to said `GroupBox`.
For example:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="{Binding Elementname=Whatever, Path=FontSize}"/>
```

or, if you want to avoid names, you could say...

```
<TextBlock FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource, Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GroupBox}, Path=FontSize}"/>
```

Which theoretically would allow you to just dump all that into a TextBlock Style you could name "GroupBoxHeaderTextBlockStyle" or something for use in future scenarios like this.